# How to take thread-dump of a java process which runs for a less time

Tags: java, unix, thread-dump

How to take threaddump of a java application which runs for a very less time. The application starts and dosent give me time to collect the pid of the process.

Am using the following for taking thread dump.

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

Probably a appropriate Unix command is what am looking for.

Regards,
Nilotpal

Comment: I have to use JRE provided kill -3 command only. No other utility or command!!

Comment: kill is not a JRE provided command. It is a UNIX command JRE responds to.

Comment: See this: http://crunchify.com/how-to-generate-java-thread-dump-programmatically/

Comment: If the application takes very little time to run, then even if you successfully take a thread dump you will catch it at some random place and the dump likely will not be meaningful.  I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Please tell us WHY you want to take a thread dump.

Comment: @JimGarrison : My application is stopping just after running for few nanoseconds and i find no error logs. So i want to take a thread dump to find what is the issue? Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to be the same user account as the Java process.
2. Run `jps -lv` to find the process
3. Run `jstack $pid`

The above two executables are found in the `$JDK_HOME/bin` directory

Finally, you might try using http://fastthread.io/ to analyze the output

Comment: I dont have jdk installed in the system but only JRE. So cannot use jps or jstack!! probably its only kill -3 that i can use!!